# vite build error: Create a React component library with Vite and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, build, vite, rollup

I'm trying to setup config to create a React component library with Vite and Typescript, before that I was using rollup, but now I want to migrate to Vite, but by doing so I got this error when I tried to run `tsc && vite build`:

```
"AccountProps" is not exported by "src/components/userAccount/userAccount.interface.ts", imported by "src/components/index.tsx".
file: C:/projects/my-lib/src/components/index.tsx:29:2
27: import UserAccount from './userAccount';
28: import UserAccountProps, {
29:   AccountProps,
      ^
30:   UserAccountMenuItemProps,
31: } from './userAccount/userAccount.interface';
error during build:
RollupError: "AccountProps" is not exported by "src/components/userAccount/userAccount.interface.ts", imported by "src/components/index.tsx".
```

`vite.config.ts` file:

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'node:path';
import { UserConfigExport, defineConfig } from 'vite';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';
import { name } from './package.json';

const app = async (): Promise<UserConfigExport> => {
  return defineConfig({
    plugins: [
      react(),
      dts({
        insertTypesEntry: true,
      }),
    ],
    resolve: {
      alias: [{ find: '@my-lib', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './src') }],
    },
    build: {
      lib: {
        entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.tsx'),
        name,
        formats: ['es', 'umd'],
        fileName: (format) => `${name}.${format}.js`,
      },
      rollupOptions: {
        external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
        output: {
          globals: {
            react: 'React',
            'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });
};
export default app;
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@my-lib/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["*.js", "src/**/*", "typings/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "storybook-static"]
}
```

The file `src/components/index.tsx` has this:

```
import { AccountProps } from './userAccount/userAccount.interface';
...
export {
  AccountProps,
  ...
}
```

And the file `userAccount.interface.ts` has this:

```
export interface AccountProps {
  ...
}
```

How can I solve this issue ?